# xoring a slice in Go

Tags: algorithm, go

So I'm trying to xor random, which is 4 bytes, with every four bytes of something. The thing is, I want to change random to ans (which is the result of the xor) and then keep going. So basically the random variable will be a fixed number the first time but will change afterwards until the loop ends. My code seems to have the correct logic, however, I keep getting
(operator ^ not defined on slice)

```
random := 4 bytes
for j:=0;j<len(something);j+=4{
ans:=something[j:j+4] ^ random
random=ans
}
```

My guess is, slice doesn't allow xor, and something will have to be slice since I'm kind of slicing the array into multiple bytes. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Refer to `crypto/cipher/xor.go` XOR bytes implementation https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/cipher/xor.go#L45-L54 and design yours.

Comment: @jeevatkm the variable "a" in the example doesn't seem to be "byte" or a slice, which makes it different than mine. Unless if I'm missing something?

Comment: In the above source code reference link; `dst`, `a`, `b` is a byte slice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application should xor the individual bytes.  Something like this:

```
var random [4]byte
for i, b := range something {
    random[i&3] ^= b  // xor b on element of random
}
```

This sets

```
random[0] = random[0] ^ something[0] ^ something[4] ....
random[1] = random[1] ^ something[1] ^ something[5] ...
... and so on
```